Civ5 Windows10 half map appears /other side grey/
Civ5 Windows10 half map appears /other side grey/ Lenovo laptop 11th Gen Intel processor Intel(R) Iris(R) XE Graphics card! Could card have gotten too hot? Starting to fail? Game was working the day before!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Half of the screen / display is grey - no map! The players pop up on the grey part. Maybe the video card is failing. The laptop gets really warm / hot.

I don’t know how to add a photo here.

Turns out the full screen option in video was checked off so checking it back in restored full screen. Not sure how that became turned off but now gone from half screen visible to full.
